# Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have uploaded some CSV files in Azure ML Studio as a Zip file. Now, when I try to read these CSV files in the R Script module using the below statements, it fails with below error. The Zip file dataset it attached to the R Script module at the Script bundle port.

Code Statements:

```
feed <- read.csv("src/KMTS-MORI-NMV-5000-1213-PATH_FEEDRATE-ACTUAL.csv", header=F)
feed <- read.csv("./src/KMTS-MORI-NMV-5000-1213-PATH_FEEDRATE-ACTUAL.csv", header=F)
feed <- read.table("src/KMTS-MORI-NMV-5000-1213-PATH_FEEDRATE-ACTUAL.csv", header=F, sep=",")
feed <- read.table("./src/KMTS-MORI-NMV-5000-1213-PATH_FEEDRATE-ACTUAL.csv", header=F, sep=",")
feed <- read.table(file="src/KMTS-MORI-NMV-5000-1213-PATH_FEEDRATE-ACTUAL.csv", header=F, sep=",")
```

Error Message:

```
Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:
 ---------- Start of error message from R ----------
 cannot open the connection

 cannot open the connection
 ----------- End of error message from R -----------
Start time: UTC 08/29/2015 23:20:28
End time: UTC 08/29/2015 23:20:37
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the files appear in a subfolder under ./src, for example by running this R script in the module.

data.set <- as.data.frame(list.files("src",full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE))