# Cannot Open Connection Error on Azure ML Studio (Running R Script)

Tags: r, azure, machine-learning

I am trying to run an R Script in Azure ML. The code runs for several hours and then stop with this error displayed:

```
Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:
---------- Start of error message from R ----------
cannot open the connection


cannot open the connection
----------- End of error message from R -----------
Start time: UTC 04/03/2017 21:09:34
End time: UTC 04/03/2017 23:33:48
```

I have ran the code in RStudio, therefore I am quite confident that the R code is not the problem. Can it be a server issue and how to avoid it?

Thanks

Comment: Similar question already exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291745/error-0063-the-following-error-occurred-during-evaluation-of-r-script . Also, you should provide your code, not only error text.

Answer (score 0):

If the code runs, verify if the problem is with the package. 
For packages that are not in Azure AML you have to load them as a dataset (after installing locally) See this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjguin/2014/09/24/how-to-upload-an-r-package-to-azure-machine-learning/